# How to create relationships (one-to-one, many-to-many) for ASP.Net Identity Users model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I need create 2 relationships for Identity.User

1. One-to-One (i know, that is so bad, but i need this)

For example, to set additional user characteristics.

2. Many-to-Many

For example, for model of Books.
User can have many books and a book can be with many users. Like in the library.

How I can do this.
Thanks.

Comment: Where *exactly* do you have difficulties doing this? Your question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

First of all. Many to Many Foreign Keys are not supported in SQL Server.  The only way to achieve this (at least the only way I know) is to create a "mapping" table.

So you need three tables User, Books and UserBooks.

I will not dive into the details on how to do it but I will point you in the right direction.

Here is a [Many To Many Tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) on how to do this.

Here is [Another Tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-ef-core.aspx)

The second one shows the table schema.  This is pretty common.

I hope this helps you achieve your goal.

Comment: i know about User - UserBooks - Books. Like a User - UserRoles - Roles in _Identity_

Comment: @Frip but in the links there is also code samples on how to express that in EF.  It shows you how to implement it in EF

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit from `IdentityUser` and pass your custom object that inherits from it in `IdentityDbContext<>`. Then your custom object can have additional members that you need including collection of books or singular properties.

Then you define the relationship when overriding `OnModelCreating` as specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#manual-configuration)

As a rough example:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUser>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Name)
        .WithMany(b => b.Books);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I quick search and i had a question. WithMany create a MANY-to-MANY relationship, or one-to-many?

Comment: And i find _.WithMany_ and _.HasMany_. What difference?

Comment: I believe it creates a one-to-many relationship so to make a many-to-many you need to use `WithMany` on your books object in the same way. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many)

Comment: In response to your other question:  The difference seems to be the order of the Parent and Child. See [this](https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/39781996/ef-core-one-to-many-relationships-hasone---withmany---vs-hasmany---withone--) which answers the question in better detail